# Return the difference between two (dates and time ) PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

i tried most of what is available on stack overflow but none seem to work.

any way i am trying to compare two (date and time formats). and calculate whether their difference is within  5 seconds of each other

the first date is the current date:

```
$today   = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

the second date is taken from mysql database:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM BUS_DATA where BusRegID = 'bus'") or die(mysql_error());
$row     = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$update_date  = $row["update_date"];
```

the answer should be segmented into years , month , days , hours , minutes ,and seconds portions.

I am running PHP Version 5.3.3

Edit: most answers give result in time frame only , I want to check whether the date matches , then compare if the time of the day is within 5 seconds , than you guys in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried to compare them yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use strtotime, it's understands almost any date formats:

```
$timeDiff = abs(strtotime($today) - strtotime($update_date));
```

this gives you the difference between dates in seconds.

Comment: Why use `strtotime` on `$today`? why not just use `time()`?

Comment: Thank you for the help seems like time and today both are are ok , but i also need the date portion for other issues , hence why i choose your as the best answer , again thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this
function getTimes($t1, $t2)
{
$timeFirst  = strtotime($t1);
$timeSecond = strtotime($t2);
$differenceInSeconds = $timeSecond - $timeFirst;
$h=0;
$m  = floor($differenceInSeconds / 60);
$s  = $differenceInSeconds % 60;
if ($m>=60)
{
  $h = floor($m / 60);
  $m = $m % 60;
}
$tim = $h.':'.$m.':'.$s;
return $tim;
}
it will return difference time in hours:min:sec
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know whether it's within 5 seconds then use Timestamps, makes it into a simple int calculation.

```
$now = time();
$test = strtotime($update_date);
if($now - $test > 5) {
    //NOT WITHIN 5 SECONDS
}
```