# how to calculate time difference between two time

Tags: php

how to calculate the **minute** difference for 2 values:-

```
strtotime("-15 minutes"); 
strtotime("now");
```

i have used below code:-

```
$diff = floor(strtotime("now") - strtotime("-15 minutes")/3600 );
```

but it gives 5 days of difference.
 please guide me where I am wrong.

Comment: Can you share some code so we can help?

Comment: Try this one

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21404551/return-the-difference-between-two-dates-and-time-php/21404759#21404759

Comment: Shouldnt it just be `$diff = floor((strtotime("now") - strtotime("-15 minutes"))/60)`? (You missed the brackets and you devided by 3600 rather than 60)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are getting hour diff with division to 3600. 15 minutes evaluates to 0 when floored. Also you are only dividing the second variable not the first with those brackets.
this should work:

```
$diff=floor((strtotime("now") - strtotime("-15 minutes"))/60);
echo $diff;// outputs 15
```

Comment: And the extra brackets, otherwise the it is dividing the -15minutes by 60